# Best approach for laying this ui out with CSS flexbox and grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I've been provided the following layout (see link) but I'm not 100% certain which approach I should take for layout. I've spent 6 hours playing around with grid and flexbox but I keep thinking "This bit should be grid not flexbox and this bit should be flexbox not grid" and I've been going back and fore. Its a bit confusing so I was looking for some advice.

In the screenshot which will need to be clicked through to, to see. The grey portions of the UI are always present, the main nav column can expand and push whats to the right of it over. As shown it will be an icon based menu and when expanded will show the icon labels.

For this reason at a high level the the logo and main nav are one column and everything to the right is another column. Hence I display grid on this. The "rows" inside the first column are two flex item elements where the parent has display: flex, flex-direction: column on it. The first item just has a min-height with the "second" item having a flex 1 on it to fill the remaining height of the container which is equal to the viewport height. This then creates the visual of a row. I follow a similar pattern in the second column but the second "row" is it's self a flex wrapper for the "rows" it contains such as the orange ,blue sections.

The orange and blue bars wont always be shown depending on the page and what happens on it but the ui has to cater for them seamlessly.

I repeated this pattern for the inner two column section (green / pink areas) where the outer container is display grid with just two columns, 1 row. Everything inside is then display: flex, flex-direction: column.

To me everything seems one dimensional as I've only really got one actual row in each column when the ui is broken down. It seems odd to me to define a grid with only one actual row hence I was thinking it should all just be flex box as I don't really have any two dimensional layout as far as I can tell. Does it actually matter? I'm an experienced CSS developer but not with grid, so theres a bit of confusion in my head right now.

This all has to work with IE10 unfortunately too and be accessible so I have to set min-heights on all the row looking bits if they have text in them as the user might increase the font size.

As with the main nav the green side panel is hidden by default but a button when clicked will cause it to slide into to view and nudge the pink column over.

If you saw this UI how should it be broken down? Any advice or insights  would be very welcome. Thank you.

[Mocked UI layout wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKlWs.png)

Comment: If you need to support IE10 I would just discard css-grid all together and do everything with just flexbox.

Comment: My recommendation without taking the IE10 as requirement would be make a grid with inside grids, at least for the important section (the gray ones).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, as a follow up I ended up ditching the grid idea and have gone exclusively with flex